# Eliminar caracteres que no sean números en datos de una consulta sql

Tags: php, sql-server

Tengo una tabla de `clientes`, en esa tabla extraigo los datos del campo `celular`.

Tengo la siguiente consulta que hago con php y SQL SERVER:

```
$consulta = "select celular FROM clientes where 
celular <> '' AND LEN(celular) >= '10' AND ind_estado = 
'1'";

$con1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $consulta);
```

Uso un ciclo while para mostrar los datos:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($con1, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))
{
  echo $row[0];
}
```

Me muestra los datos normalmente (por ejemplo):

`2977350086`

`300 480 04 08`

`300 702 33 06`

`300-454-52-13`

`3105115514-CARLOS H`

Sucede que necesito por así decirlo "formatear" los números para que no tengan nada aparte de números, osea eliminar letras, espacios en blanco, guiones etc.

Nota: Vi un par de post donde tenian problemas similares y recomendaban usar la funcion `explode` lo intente pero me sale un error debido a que cada dato es un array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intentalo con `preg_split` asi:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($con1, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))
{
  $numeros = preg_split("/[\s-]+/", $row[0]);
  echo "<p>";
  foreach ($numeros as $num) {
      if (is_numeric($num)) {
          echo $num;
      }
  }
  echo "</p>";
}
```

Comment: No me funciona, por ejemplo este número `300-454-52-13` me lo deja así `300`

Comment: A mi me funciona bien, lo copieaste exacto?

Comment: Si amigo esta igual a como lo pusiste, los números que se deberían de formatear quedan recortados, por ejemplo los que tienen espacios o guiones en medio

Comment: Disculpa, el código es correcto si funciona, pero al intentar mostrar los números en una etiqueta html, por ejemplo en `p` los números corregidos me salen separados por un salto de linea

Comment: Necesitas poner el `p` afuera del `foreach`.

Comment: Pero para poder mostrar los datos el `echo` tiene que estar dentro del `foreach` y el `echo` va adentro de la etiqueta, no?

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta.

Comment: Funciona con los espacios y guiones pero también necesito eliminar las letras, por ejemplo por ahi me quedo un registro asi `3507618866YEN`

Comment: Facil, ya edite.